# Custom fstream implementation for Arduino

Tags: c++, arduino, io, stl, arduino-uno

Long story short, I'm using a C++ library for writing to a proprietary file format on an Arduino microcontroller. I'm using PlatformIO as my development platform and the Arduino_Due_SD_HSCMI library for SD card interaction.

The file format library uses `std::fstring` for file system interaction. This, of course, will not work on Arduino. I need to find a way to coax the file format library into using Arduino_Due_SD_HSCMI instead. My initial plan was to derive a class from `std::fstring` or a parent with the same interface which is implemented using the SD card library.

After researching this, it seems to be a difficult and non-optimal route. My questions are these:

1. What is the best way to coerce this file format library into using the SD card library for reading/writing with minimal/no changes to the file format library?
2. Is it possible to implement an `std::filebuf` and create an `std::fstream` which uses that? The available constructors would appear to say not.
3. Is it possible to create an `std::fstring` which writes to an intermediary buffer of my design, which then writes using the SD card library?